'Machine type temporarily unavailable' when deploying model endpoint
I’m trying to deploy a model on GCP Vertex AI, but I keep encountering the error:

Machine type temporarily unavailable, please deploy with a different machine type or retry.

I've attempted the following machine types (with and without GPU) in the us-central1 region:

n1-standard-16
n1-standard-32
a2-highgpu-1g (1x A100 GPU)

The error takes a long time to appear, and the deployment ultimately fails. I’ve successfully deployed the Gemma and Llama3 models from Model Garden, but I cannot get them to deploy to an endpoint.
Here’s one stack trace I encountered, though most of the time I only receive the "Machine type temporarily unavailable" error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/workspace/vllm/vllm/entrypoints/api_server.py", line 458, in 
    asyncio.run(run_server(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/workspace/vllm/vllm/entrypoints/api_server.py", line 421, in run_server
    app = await init_app(args, llm_engine)
  File "/workspace/vllm/vllm/entrypoints/api_server.py", line 402, in init_app
    if llm_engine is not None else AsyncLLMEngine.from_engine_args(
  File "/workspace/vllm/vllm/engine/async_llm_engine.py", line 679, in from_engine_args
    engine_config = engine_args.create_engine_config()
  File "/workspace/vllm/vllm/engine/arg_utils.py", line 951, in create_engine_config
    device_config = DeviceConfig(device=self.device)
  File "/workspace/vllm/vllm/config.py", line 1088, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to infer device type")
RuntimeError: Failed to infer device type

I have the following questions:

Is there any way to check if a machine type is available before deploying an endpoint to avoid long wait times followed by failure?
What machine types should I be using to successfully deploy language generation models on GCP Vertex AI?
Are there any recommended regions for this type of deployment?


SO is a question and answer site. If you have more than one question, you need to create more than one post in which to ask each one. For more information about how the site works, see the [help].

Normally Vertex AI automatically allocate a machine for you but you can try a custom job instead, where you can set all those parameters.
You can check out this Configure compute resources for custom training
.set_memory_request('208G').set_cpu_request("32") 

To check if a machine type is available before deploying an endpoint  Run the following command:

gcloud compute machine-types list --zones=YOUR\_ZONE
Or you can check through this doc what are the Accelerators available in that reginos Region considerations
You can also refer Configure compute resources for prediction  and Configure compute resources for custom training
For detailed investigation you can create a public issue tracker  describing your issue and vote [+1] and Eng team will look on the issue .
